# Identifying files contained within a docker image (or Application dependencies)

Tags: docker

I'm currently running a project with Docker, and I have this question. Is there any possible way that you can know what are the exact files that are contained in a docker image, without running that image ?

In a different way, I'm scheduling docker containers to run on the cloud based on the binaries/libraries they use, so that containers with common dependencies (have common binaries and libraries) are scheduled to run on the same host thus share these dependencies on the hosts os. Is there a possible way to identify the dependencies / do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could run [`docker diff`](http://docs.docker.io/reference/commandline/cli/#diff) on each layer to see what files were added. It is not very succinct, but it should be complete.

Alternatively your distro and programming language may have tools that help identify which dependencies have been added. For example, Python users can check the output of `pip freeze` and Debian users can check the output of `dpkg --get-selections` to check on what system packages have been installed.

Comment: I guess that is the most practical thing. Despite my question was, "without actually running a container" .. but yea, probably no way better than using diff :) Thank you :)